# How to fix error with Material-ui Tabs, none of tabs children match '2'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am starting to build a Header component for my react app using Material-ui. While building the Toolbar I added a `Tabs` component and inside added three `Tab` components. One for Home, contact-us, and to logout. I realize though that whenever I press any other tab other than logout everything is fine. However, as soon as I press logout it throws the following error:

```
index.js:1 Material-UI: The value provided to the Tabs component is invalid.
None of the Tabs' children match with `2`.
You can provide one of the following values: 0, 1.
```

When reading the documentation and looking at the error more closely I realized it has something to do with the value state and setValue property. So I am unsure if my problem is that I have to set a variable to hold all my info and then I just make a reference to the variable in my Tab component. Regardless, my goal is to just get the logout tab working in any way that does not produce this error message.

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import { 
    AppBar, 
    Typography, 
    Tabs, 
    Tab, 
    SwipeableDrawer,
    IconButton,
    Button
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import useMediaQuery from "@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery";
import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { logout } from '../../../actions/auth';



const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    toolbarMargin: {
        ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    },
      player: {
          marginBottom: "2em"
      },
      tabContainer: {
          marginLeft: "auto",
          
      },
      tab: {
          textTransform: "none",
          fontWeight: 400,
          fontSize: "1.3rem",
          color: "#000000"
       
      },
      bar: {
          backgroundColor: "#e5e5e5"
          
      },
      name: {
          color: "#000000"
      },
      drawerIcon: {
        height: "40px",
        width: "40px"
      },
      drawerIconContainer: {
          marginLeft: "auto",
          "&:hover": {
              backgroundColor: "transparent"
          }
      }
      
}));

const Header = ({ auth: { isAuthenticated, loading }, logout }) => {



    const classes = useStyles();
    const theme = useTheme();
    const iOS = process.browser && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent);
    const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'));
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
    const [openDrawer, setOpenDrawer] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    };



    const authLinks =(
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} className={classes.tabContainer} indicatorColor="primary">
            <Tab className={classes.tab} component={Link} to="/dashboard" label="Home" disableRipple />
            <Tab className={classes.tab} component={Link} to="/contact-us" label="Contact Us" disableRipple />
            <Tab className={classes.tab} onClick={logout} label="Logout" disableRipple />
        </Tabs>
    );


    const guestLinks = (
        
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} className={classes.tabContainer} indicatorColor="primary">
            <Tab component={Link} to="/register" label="Register"/>
            <Tab component={Link} to="/login" label="Login"/>
        </Tabs>
        
    );


    

    // const drawer = (
    //     <React.Fragment>
    //         <SwipeableDrawer disableBackdropTransition={!iOS} disableDiscovery={iOS} open={openDrawer} onClose={()=> setOpenDrawer(false)} onOpen={()=> setOpenDrawer(true)}>
    //             Contact Us
    //         </SwipeableDrawer>

    //         <IconButton className={classes.drawerIconContainer} onClick={() => setOpenDrawer(!openDrawer)} disableRipple>
    //             <MenuIcon className={classes.drawerIcon} />
    //         </IconButton>
    //     </React.Fragment>
    // );


    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <AppBar className={classes.bar}>
                <Toolbar> 
                    <Typography variant="h5" className={classes.name}>SilverStone</Typography>
                    { !loading && (<Fragment>{ isAuthenticated ? authLinks : guestLinks } </Fragment>) }
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <div className={classes.toolbarMargin} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

Header.propTypes = {
    logout: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout })(Header);
```

Comment: Looks like your the logout tab onClick method is getting executed, before handle change gets called. once your onClick method finishes the it calls handleChange during that time the tab component is gone.
You will have to call logout in handle change when value is 2.

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma I tried what you recommended but it still didn't work

Comment: that unfortunate, But it has something to do with that event only. can you make the third tab as button component and try?

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma Yes, I have but when I do I get an error with ```Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute indicator```. Also, I get ``` React does not recognize the `selectionFollowsFocus` prop on a DOM element```